# Spring Integration Testing Service Layer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-integration, beancreationexception

I have build a small application using Spring Integration. In which i have service activator, services and repository interface which are extending CrudRepository.
While writing jUnit Test cases for service i am problem. I wrote one test case as below but i try to run that. I am getting exception.

Test Cases

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/medicineIntegration.xml", "classpath:/doseIntegration.xml"})
public class DoseServiceTest {

@Autowired
private DoseService doseService;

@MockBean
private DoseRepository doseRepository;

@Test
public void testSaveDose() {
    Dose dose = createDose();
    Mockito.when(doseRepository.save(dose)).thenReturn(dose);
    assertThat(doseService.saveDose(dose)).isEqualTo(dose);
}

private Dose createDose() {
    Dose dose = new Dose();
    dose.setDoseValue("120");
    return dose;
}
```

Below is the error i am getting while running the test case.

```
Field medicineRepo in com.cerner.api.service.MedicineService required a bean 
of type 'com.cerner.api.dao.MedicineRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.cerner.api.dao.MedicineRepository' in 
your configuration.

2018-12-10 22:57:14.261 ERROR 21524 --- [           main] 
o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing 
TestExecutionListener 
[org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@32115b28] 
to prepare test instance [com.cerner.api.service.DoseServiceTest@2f0bfe17]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209) ~[.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 
'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'medicineServiceActivator' while setting 
bean property 'targetObject'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'medicineServiceActivator': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'medicineService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'medicineService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'medicineRepo'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'com.cerner.api.dao.MedicineRepository' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:827) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'medicineServiceActivator': Unsatisfied 
dependency expressed through field 'medicineService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'medicineService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'medicineRepo'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'com.cerner.api.dao.MedicineRepository' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'medicineService': Unsatisfied dependency e 
expressed through field 'medicineRepo'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'com.cerner.api.dao.MedicineRepository' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'com.cerner.api.dao.MedicineRepository' 
available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
... 66 common frames omitted
```

I am not sure why the bean in not getting instantiated for the Repositories(Interfaces) 
Thanks In advance for the help.

**Updated**

Below the service class.

```
@Service
@Qualifier
public class MedicineService {

@Autowired
private MedicineRepository medicineRepo;

private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

public List<Medicine> getAllMedicines() {
    List<Medicine> medicine = new ArrayList<Medicine>();
    medicineRepo.findAll().forEach(medicine::add);
    log.info("Returning from service with medicine data");
    return medicine;
}

public Medicine saveMedicine(Medicine medicine) {
    return medicineRepo.save(medicine);
}

public Medicine updateMedicine(Medicine medicine) {
    return medicineRepo.save(medicine);
}

public void deleteMedicine(int id) {
    medicineRepo.deleteById(id);
}
}
```

Repository Interface

```
@Repository
public interface MedicineRepository extends CrudRepository<Medicine,Integer> 
{

}
```

Comment: Your problem is `Field medicineRepo in com.cerner.api.service.MedicineService required a bean`, but you fully don't show how that `MedicineService` is represented in your configuration.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Please find the updated part with my service and repository class and the xml configuration.

Comment: While doing some research i have gone through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795617/instantiation-of-bean-failed-specified-class-is-an-interface link. But i am not sure to use @PostConstruct

Comment: I think you still doesn't show something in your project. It might be a fact that you don't specify a main `@SpringBootApplication` class so your `MedicineRepository` is just not visible for the test because there is no proper scan.

Comment: Fully not related to Spring Integration though...

Comment: I have figure out the Solution.  Annotation SpringBootTest was creating the issue.
Thanks @ArtemBilan

Comment: Cool! You can share it as an answer and accept it yourself